# Basic formula working within Google Sheets, but not Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, syntax-error

I am trying to write a code that returns the 7 digit ID in box A4, & if it includes a certain phrase "AUD", it will return a blank cell.

The formula `=IF(COUNTIF(C4,"*AUD*"),"",RIGHT(C4,7))` works perfectly fine when pasted into column A, but once imported into the script, it gives me the error

> "Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 45 file: CleanData.gs"

```
function idClean () {
  /** getID */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A4:A");
    cell.setFormula("=IF(COUNTIF(C4,"*AUD*"),"",RIGHT(C4,7))");
}
```

I have tried replacing parenthesis and other formulas. The original formula "=RIGHT(C4,7)" works fine when put into the script, but once I expand it gives me errors. I was expecting this formula to work because I copied it directly over from the sheet.

Ideally, the formula would check if there were any names that did not include any numbers --> making that box ("A" = blank), and if it did have numbers at the end putting those in.

Comment: Use template literals: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+template+literals+formula